# Apps Script in google sheet error : TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Plate')

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I am writing code using ChatGPT, It work perfectly in the previous code (Exactly the same name and format of previous one but this one dont work)(Try changing the name of the error one but still error)

**The code is to open pop-up form  --> input data --> send into sheet('Car')

*Picture attached is HTML Code and error said

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Plate')" addDataToCar    @ ACar.gs:14

P.S 1 Very much thx in advance to those who helped and I hope this will help another newbie, too
P.S 2 I've looked through similar questions on this site. The problem is that I'm too new, so I can't adapt those solutions,

Here's my full GS and HTML Code

GS Code************

```
function openForm() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('AddCar')
      .setWidth(400)
      .setHeight(600);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .showModalDialog(html, 'Add Car');
}

function addDataToCar(formData) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Car');
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 13).getValues()[0];
  
  var data = [];
  data.push(formData.Plate); 
  data.push(formData.Province);
  data.push(formData.Type);
  data.push(formData.Brand);
  data.push(formData.Model);
  data.push(formData.License_date);
  data.push(formData.Chassise);
  data.push(formData.Engine);
  data.push(formData.HorsePower);
  data.push(formData.Size);
  data.push(formData.Owner);
  data.push(formData.be_under);
  data.push(formData.Extra);
  
  var newRow = [];
  
  // Add data to the 'Car' sheet
  sheet.appendRow(newRow);
}
```

HTML Code(named it 'AddCar')**********

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
    <form id="carForm">
        <label for="Plate">ทะเบียนรถ:</label>
        <input type="text" id="Plate" name="Plate"><br><br>

        <label for="Province">จังหวัด:</label>
        <input type="text" id="Province" name="Province"><br><br>

        <label for="Type">ประเภทรถ:</label>
        <input type="text" id="Type" name="Type"><br><br>

        <label for="Brand">ยี่ห้อ:</label>
        <input type="text" id="Brand" name="Brand"><br><br>

        <label for="Model">รุ่น:</label>
        <input type="text" id="Model" name="Model"><br><br>

        <label for="License_date">วันจดทะเบียน:</label>
        <input type="date" id="License_date" name="License_date"><br><br>

        <label for="Chassise">เลขคัสซี:</label>
        <input type="text" id="Chassise" name="Chassise"><br><br>

        <label for="Engine">เลขเครื่อง:</label>
        <input type="text" id="Engine" name="Engine"><br><br>

        <label for="HorsePower">แรงม้า:</label>
        <input type="text" id="HorsePower" name="HorsePower"><br><br>

        <label for="Size">ขนาด:</label>
        <input type="text" id="Size" name="Size"><br><br>

        <label for="Owner">เจ้าของ:</label>
        <input type="text" id="Owner" name="Owner"><br><br>

        <label for="be_under">ผู้ดูแล:</label>
        <input type="text" id="be_under" name="be_under"><br><br>

        <label for="Extra">หมายเหตุเพิ่มเติม:</label>
        <textarea id="Extra" name="Extra" rows="3" cols="50"></textarea><br><br>

        <input type="button" value="เพิ่มข้อมูล" onclick="submitCData()">
    </form>

    <script>
        function submitCData() {
  var formData = {
    Plate: document.getElementById('Plate').value,
    Province: document.getElementById('Province').value,
    Type: document.getElementById('Type').value,
    Brand: document.getElementById('Brand').value,
    Model: document.getElementById('Model').value,
    License_date: document.getElementById('License_date').value,
    Chassise: document.getElementById('Chassise').value,
    Engine: document.getElementById('Engine').value,
    HorsePower: document.getElementById('HorsePower').value,
    Size: document.getElementById('Size').value,
    Owner: document.getElementById('Owner').value,
    be_under: document.getElementById('be_under').value,
    Extra: document.getElementById('Extra').value
  };

  // Log the form data to the console (for testing)
  console.log(formData);

  // Call Google Apps Script function to add data to 'Car' sheet
  google.script.run.addDataToCar(formData);

  // Close the form after submission (optional)
  google.script.host.close();

    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code as text.

Comment: edited! Thx for fast responding. Sending Appreciation to my bro :)

Comment: Is this error happening when you run the script from the code editor? Or after clicking the button in your Modal?

Comment: its happen when i ran the code editor
**** i just worked on it whole night, now the code works fine (its usable now) but the error when running on code editor still persist. Wonder why.